# Heirarchies of permissions in Django - inheriting from models and from other permissions

Tags: python, django, permissions

Django allows you to give users and groups of users custom permissions on objects (and [`django-guardian`](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/) adds some nice ways of using this). There are various ways of putting users into hierarchies. What I'd like to do is add two types of hierarchies to the permissions themselves. For example if someone has a given permission on a `Book` object, I want them to implicitly have that permission on each `Page` object. Also, if someone has an `change` permission on a `Page`, I want them to implicitly have the `view` permission on that `Page`.

In sum, I want `page.has_permission('view', user)` to check both `page.has_permission('*edit*', user)` and `page *.book* .has_permission('view', user)`, and for `book.has_permission('view', user)` to itself check `book.has_permission('*edit*', user)`. (Asterisks just for emphasis.)

I don't need anything as complex as [`django-rules`](https://github.com/maraujop/django-rules), and I prefer the generic foreign key approach as I will not have large numbers and it keeps the model structure clean and focused. I'd like to avoid repeating the logic for these permission relationships in views, or cluttering models, and I'd ideally keep this permission structure centralized somewhere, ideally declaratively. For example

```
perm_hierarchy = {'view': ['edit', 'delete', ]}
model_perm_hierarchy = { Page : [Chapter, ],
                         Chapter : [Book, ]}
```

Then a layer that when checking for `'view'` on `Page` checks for `'edit'` and `'delete'` permissions on that `Page` object.

And similarly when checking `Page` for a permission, checks `Chapter` for the same permission (if that same named permission is defined for `Chapter`).

Very happy to be told I'm thinking about this wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I document a solution using django-rules on top of django-guardian in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306677/can-django-guardian-and-django-rules-be-used-together/37307852#37307852)